# Break some sequences of data into several adjacent pieces

Tags: r, list, sequence, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a couple of sequences which I want to break into series of adjacent numbers. The sequences are nested within a list of individuals such that the size of the window that contains the adjacent numbers varies from one individual to another. Here are some example data:

```
#The sequences of three individuals
sequences <- list(c(1,2,3,5,6), c(2,3,4,5,6), c(1,3,4,6,7))

#The window size that contains the adjacent numbers
#for the first individual, 2 adjacent numbers should be bonded together and for the second, 3 should be bonded, etc.
windowsize <- list(2,3,4)

#The breakdown of the adjacent numbers should look like:
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2
[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2 3
[[1]][[3]]
[1] 3 5
[[1]][[4]]
[1] 5 6

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2 3 4
[[2]][[2]]
[1] 3 4 5
[[2]][[3]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 1 3 4 6
[[3]][[2]]
[1] 3 4 6 7
```

I have a much larger dataset than this and so I am thinking maybe writing a function will be the way to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `Map` with `embed` from `base R` - loop over the corresponding elements of 'sequences', 'windowsize' in `Map`, create a matrix with `embed` with `dimension` specified as the element (`y`) from 'windowsize' and use `asplit` to split by row (`MARGIN = 1`)

```
Map(function(x, y) asplit(embed(x, y)[, y:1], 1), sequences, windowsize)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 3 5

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 5 6


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 4 5 6


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 1 3 4 6

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 3 4 6 7
```

---

If we want a `matrix`, just remove the `asplit`

```
Map(function(x, y) embed(x, y)[, y:1], sequences, windowsize)
[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    3    5
[4,]    5    6

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
[2,]    3    4    5
[3,]    4    5    6

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    4    6
[2,]    3    4    6    7
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't really need to create a list of list here since the sublists are all rectangular.  Suggest creating a list of matrices instead.  We used sequences and windowsize from the question but since windowsize could be represented by a numeric vector that probably makes more sense.  If you want lists anyways then use the commented out f instead.

```
library(zoo)
# split2 <- function(x) split(x, 1:nrow(x))
# f <- function(x, w) split2(rollapply(x, w, c))
f <- function(x, w) rollapply(x, w, c)
Map(f, sequences, windowsize)
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    3    5
[4,]    5    6

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
[2,]    3    4    5
[3,]    4    5    6

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    4    6
[2,]    3    4    6    7
```

Comment: Thank you @G. Grothendieck. Yes, I agree. A list of matricies output looks better.